# error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++

I found this compiling error very odd .
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
I'm compiling under MVC++ Express 2010 here's the code :

The error indicate that it's from line 8 .

```
1    int m;
2    vector <string> grid;
3
4    cin >> m;
5
6    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
7       string s; 
8   cin >> s;
9        grid.push_back(s);
10    }
```

Comment: Could you show your header?

Comment: Have you included all necessary headers?

Comment: Obviously, you're missing headers (and the `std::` which should precede names from the standard library).  Beyond that, even once it compiles, the code is broken, since you're using the results of `>>` without verifying that the operation has succeeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#include <string>`. Also if you don't have them add `#include <iostream>` and `#include <vector>`.

Comment: And if I have them included, but still have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include<string>` and `#include<iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error appeared when I did this:

```
volatile int a;
std::cin << a;
```

Obviously, the << operator is not overloaded for volatile int and thus removing 'volatile' is the solution.