# Right-hand operand error on string when using cin

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, calculator, cin

I'm trying to make a basic calculator that will use a `do-while` loop and prompt the user for an answer of whether the user wishes to rerun the calculator from the beginning.

I run into the following error at the `cin` for the string literal answer of `yes` or `no`:

```
<Error C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)>
```

How can I solve this?

```
int main()
{
    double x;
    double z;
    char o;
    string a;
    char Y, y;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please input a value for x: " << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Please input a value for z: " << endl;
        cin >> z;
        cout << "Please pick an operation to do: * / + -" << endl;
        cin >> o;

        switch (o) {
            case '+':
                cout << x << " + " << z << " = " << x + z << endl;
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << x << " - " << z << " = " << x - z << endl;
                break;
            case '*':
                cout << x << " * " << z << " = " << x*z << endl;
                break;
            case '/':
                if (z != 0)
                {
                    x / z;
                    cout << x << " / " << z << " = " << x / z << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Can not divide by zero! Nice try, Pedersen!" << endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout << "/n/n/tThank you for using my calculator!" << endl << endl;
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << "/n/n/tDid you want to run the calculator again?" << endl << endl;
        cin >> a;
    }while (a == "Yes" || a == "yes");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: Include the `<string>` header. In order to keep the existing code as-is after the include add a `using namespace std;`. Tip: you can use the free AStyle tool to format your code (many editors also do that).

Comment: On a side note, the newline and tab characters require a backslash, not a forward one. So you should type `\n` and `\t`, not `/n` and `/t`.

Comment: Also, it appears to me that youre code will clear the console before any output can even be read. (Thats what i assumed `system("cls")` does). Might add a wait for enter key or something like cin.

Comment: While we're at it, the "naked" `x / z;` statement in your division case is superfluous.

Comment: now for some reason my code now wont hold the answer like it used to.  That include <string> worked but now my program doesn't want to hold and display the answer to each operation

Comment: Ok i appreciate the help everyone I got it now appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a solution to your problem can be found @ source: [error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095237/error-c2678-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-left-hand-operand-of)

you need to `#include <string>`